# Comment appeler notre salon de clavardage ? What should our chatroom name be?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

Notre [salon de clavardage](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/french-language-and-usage) porte actuellement le nom générique « French Language and Usage » avec pour description « General discussion for french.stackexchange.com | Bienvenue à tous ! ». Et si nous lui donnions un meilleur nom ? Faites vos propositions !

---

Our [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/french-language-and-usage) is currently named “French Language and Usage” with “General discussion for french.stackexchange.com | Bienvenue à tous !” as description. Would it now be a good time to think about a better name? Let's suggest!

Comment: Au fait, nous devrions maintenir le "Bienvenue à tous !"

Comment: Why is this still undecided? :P

Comment: @Alenanno: Because this is not linguistics and the moderators on FLU are not utter tyrants ;)

Comment: @Evpok Are you saying I'm one? :P

Answer (score 11):

**Chez Cosette**

[Cosette](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosette) est une francophone (fictive) bien connue.

Une [causette](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/causette), c'est un *chat room*, suivant le [Répertoire terminologique](http://franceterme.culture.fr/FranceTerme/publications.html?ANNEE=2000) français.

Comment: Et cela nous rapproche de la littérature de Victor Hugo...

Answer (score 2):

I like [*La pétaudière*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/p%C3%A9taudi%C3%A8re). I think it has to be in French and somewhat in-joke-ish. I am fine with the current description.

Comment: Google Translate tells me that this means 'bear garden'.  As I'm not a native French speaker, could someone please explain the joke to me? :-)

Comment: *Une pétaudière* is the name for a place that would be, in English, *a shambles* (“a state of total disorder”), or *a pigsty*.

Answer (score 2):

Je trouve que ***le salon*** ou ***la taverne*** conviendraient très bien.

Comment: Il y a déjà "The Tavern on the Meta".

Answer (score 2):

La Stackadémie ! Référence à l'académie française évidemment, haut lieu plein de vieux sages qui discutent du bon emploi de la langue française.

Answer (score 1):

Peut-être un jeu de mots fondé sur le mot emprunté "chat".  Si nous avons un [chat noir](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/195/8) comme mascotte, nous pouvons dire:

> Le bavard chat noir

... ou quelque chose.  Je ne peux pas trouver un mot qui veut dire *bavard* ou *éloquent* etc. mais ressemble à *noir*...  Des autres peuvent imaginer une meilleure phrase, je suis sûr.  :-D

---

Perhaps we could use a pun based on the loanword "chat" (also means "cat" in French).  If we have a [black cat](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/195/8) as our mascot, we could say:

> Le bavard chat noir (the chatty black c[h]at)

... or something.  I can't find a word that means "chatty" or "eloquent" etc. but looks like "noir" (black)... other people can imagine a better phrase, I'm sure.  :-D

Comment: Le [chat marré](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chamarrer) ? Le [chat aux tics](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chaotique) (N.B. pas prononcé pareil) ? Le [chat rit & varie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/charivari) ?

Comment: @gilles Les chats faux?

Comment: @Knu: On a trouvé plus gai comme nom…