# New site design launched

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see, the new design just went live! At this point, we are done with major revisions to the design (although you can still report CSS/styling bugs by starting a new post and tagging it with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)). Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/890/french-language-site-design-and-logo-draft).

I have really enjoyed working with you all to create this theme. Thank you for being an awesome community, and I hope you enjoy the new design!

Comment: Love it, thanks!

Comment: The icon is way too small to clearly identify the "fr".

Comment: Wait the design means the site just got promoted? Or it means the site had already gotten promoted, but the site just got around to the new design now? I'm asking because I thought a new design means congratulations are in order but well apparently not? Idk but well tres bien if ever. (I finished french on duolingo. Lol!)

Comment: @BCLC see [this post](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/865/11659) for context :D

Comment: @anonymous2 ' You’ve been waiting almost three years' - ok lol congrats then. tres bien.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's too late to change anything, but I've noticed that the pattern doesn't "loop" properly, and the seam is often in a spot where it's visible.

Would it be possible to edit the repeating background image so that it loops nicely and makes a continuous curve?

[image]

Same thing for the grey version on the meta site:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I wish that the background on meta was more black on Chrome with dark mode (`chrome://flags/`: `#enable-force-dark`):

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but we don't support dark mode on the network sites at all, so it seems like something your browser is doing, not us. :)