# Ads in the sidebar

Tags: discussion, design, site-promotion

If we design some nice sidebar ads, perhaps based on our cool [1920's posters motif](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/195/8), can we get them promoted in the sidebar like [the ones I've seen for Parenting](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257/did-you-know-that-we-have-flyers) (another beta site)?

I'm really addressing this to a mod like @RobertCartaino or @cabbey as I'm not sure what the process is for getting this happening or how Parenting did it.  Even they [don't seem](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239/what-can-we-do-to-help-boost-traffic-now-that-the-latest-school-session-has-star) to [really know](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/does-anyone-know-why-parenting-got-ads-in-the-sidebar).  :-D

Comment: I got the semi-official word that it was a one-time thing. I don't get the feeling that there's a plan to do it again.

Comment: That sucks. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Sur *Code Review* (un autre site en béta) nous avons simplement "volé" l'idée de *Programming Puzzles & Code Golf* (qu'ils ont probablement volés ailleurs!) et créé une "méta-question" ([ici](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1781/lets-make-community-ads)) permettant aux membres de la communauté de soumettre des publicités et de voter pour les meilleures; la publicité gagnante s'est retrouvée publiée sur *Stack Overflow* et *Programmers.StackExchange* - ces sites ont une "méta-question" portant l'étiquette [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads), qui existent justement à cet effet.

---

On *Code Review* (another beta site), we simply stole *Programming Puzzles & Code Golf*'s idea (which was probably "stolen" from somewhere else!) and created a meta-question ([here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1781/lets-make-community-ads)), allowing community members to create, and submit ads, and vote for the best ones; the winning entry was published on *Stack Overflow* and *Programmers.StackExchange* - these sites have a meta-question tagged with [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads), which exists specifically for that purpose.