# New voting buttons vs intended site design, any chance at accessibility? / Ça se voit, les nouvelles flèches ?

Tags: support, feature-request, design

It's hard to see the contrast on our main  site with the new voting buttons, isn't it?  To me after voting it's a very light blue within a quite thin darker blue black circle outline.  The color of the voted arrow is the same and the only difference is the slight shading around it and a slightly darker circle.  On our meta it's a black circle filled in black with the arrow white, much more visibly voted than the inverse; without a vote it's a white circle and black arrow.

After [our recent custom theme](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/890/french-language-site-design-and-logo-draft) which shows the exact colors in use (so carefully designed by Katie, @Disco St Ives and published just eight months ago), this seems like it needs improvement.  So soon after such intentional work. And for so many.

[Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows?cb=1) has this response to the recent change. QED.  Les dés sont jetés.  I'm sure many sites are seeing (or not seeing) a similar problem.  Is there a way to help accessibility with contrast for our main?  Our meta is clear by contrast, no problem there.

I would like to see more contrast on the main.  May we join the queue?

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: @None  On dirait *peu clair* : (

Comment: Mon cerveau voit le cercle du bas et sa flèche plus à gauche que le cercle et la flèche du haut.

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t Mince. Je commence à me douter là aussi. 
 Maintenant la barre d'outils est plus grande pour moi, c'est trop pour le site mobile peut-être ?