# Please make contrast between the buttons and the background color

Tags: feature-request, design

When I asked my first question I found no contrast between the "Post your question"  card and the background color.

While without the contrast we are still able to post our questions I think it would seem more beautiful if there is a significant contrast.

Also, the deep red color of the words "Discard draft" in that deep blue background isn't suitable to my eyes.

While the background has three different colors I don't think that that red color fits any of them.

[image: Contrast]

Comment: Related: https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/935/1893